# Facebook development problem on return canvas url

Tags: facebook, url, canvas

I have an application i.e `apps.facebook.com/myappnamegoeshere/`

Its canvas URL is i.e `subdomain.mysite.com`

When Facebook wants to authenticate me it returns my canvas URL, but it addssomething like this to my URL:

```
subdomain.mysite.com/amegoeshere/?authtoken=bla bla...
```

My page gives 404 error, naturally.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: so you need it to be: `subdomain.mysite.com/?authtoken=bla bla...` ? what is your app settings?

Comment: same problem with my aplication... it redirecting me to absolute URL of my application.

In mozilla works fine, but in chrome not remain on the page (http://apps.facebook.com/example/), it going to www.mysite.com/example/ .... :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your facebook application settings are correct and the canvas call back url is what you want it to be.

-Roozbeh